# Mac app unable to read app bundle resources

Tags: swift, xcode, sandbox, macos-sierra, entitlements

I have a sandboxed Mac application that will no longer launch fully on Sierra. It seems as though it's unable to read the app bundle directories.

There is a folder located at `~/library/Containers/com.company.app/Data/Gallery/`. On fresh installs the app is unable to read from this directory with Sierra, where on OS versions previous to Sierra it could. Current installs updating the app also have access to the directory.

This is related to an entitlement that we're missing but after trying the following it's still not working. When we disable sandboxing the app launches and works as expected.

We've tried these by adding them manually to the entitlements.plist;

```
com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write
com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write
com.apple.security.temporary-exception.shared-preference.read-write
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This issue is currently blocking any future app updates. Unfortunately a recent update somehow snuck through review processes with this bug so we're in hot water...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Any luck with this issue?
I'm having a similar problem with my Java app.
I requested technical assistance but I was told it's a bug and that I need to file a bug report. I filed a bug report but not hopeful that anyone will look at that bug report.